# CSS style not applying

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to run this simple code, but it appears that some declarations in css are not taking effect (mainly centering of text and images being placed side by side w/o bullets).

When I ran the code using StackOverflow's code snippet tool, the styles seem to apply. But when I run the code in Chrome, IE, and Firefox, the styles to the `<ul>` and text don't seem to be working.

```css
#smedia-container {
 position:relative;
 max-width: 302px;
 max-height: 110px;
 text-align: center;
}
.smedia-header {
 background-color: #b90021;
 color: #fff;
 min-height: 32px;
 
}
.smedia-icons li {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>social media bar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="smedia-bar.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="smedia-container">
 <div class="smedia-header">
  Social Media
 </div>
 <p> Follow Us </p>
 <ul class="smedia-icons">
  <li><a href="https://www.instragram.com"><img src="instragram.png" alt=" "> </a> </li>
  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="facebook.png" alt=" "></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="twitter.png" alt=" "></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.flicker.com"><img src="flicker.png" alt=" "></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com.com"><img src="youtube.png" alt=" "></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.tumblr.com"><img src="tumbler.png" alt=" "></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I validated both the html and css using online validators and both came back valid.

Waiting a while after clearing my cache, updating my text editor (sublime3) restarting my computer, deleting all styles associated with the ul.smedia-icons li elements, saving the doc and reinserting the style in the code, it seems to work fine now. Even the text-centering style seems to work now. It even works across multiple browsers so I think it might have been a bug in either my text editor or computer system. Just glad to know my syntax and logic was correct. Thanks for all who helped me through this!

Comment: Your issue is difficult (or impossible) to troubleshoot without a problem we can reproduce. Are other styles in `smedia-bar.css` working? Are you able to provide a link to the problematic website?

Comment: There are styles in the stylesheet that are applying ( was able to sucessfully add a background-color). I'm running the files from my desktop. I can add a screenshot if that would be helpful.

Comment: unfortunately my reputation is not high enough to include a screenshot. sorry :(

Comment: In my opinion, a screen-shot won't help to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working in the snippet and not on your desktop the issue is most likely your link reference to the CSS file.  With the code you've shown us the css file must be in the same directory as your html file.  They cannot be in separate folders.

As a side note, you will want to update all your external links to also include "http://" in front of them.  Otherwise none of the links will actually work.

e.g. `<a href="www.instragram.com">` should actually be

`<a href="http://www.instragram.com">`

Comment: Both files are located in the same folder. I know that the stylesheet is linked corectly because a background-color style I've declared in the css file is displaying properly in my browser. For some reason the ul styles and text centering styles are not applying and I don't know why

Comment: as an additional side note: the protocol isn't required for the link to be valid. `href="//www.instragram.com"` will work for both http and https

Comment: True if it's on a web server somewhere, but it won't work if it's being used locally on a desktop environment without a web server.  *I'm making an assumption that OP isn't on the level to run a local web server yet.

Comment: I understand that but can anyone help with the ul list and text centering  styles not applying? Is the code that I've provided correct logically?

Comment: @web-dev the code (aside from the links) you've provided is correct.  I've even taken the code and ran it locally on my end and get the same results as you see in the snippet.  There's got to be more to the story that we aren't seeing yet.

Comment: is there a way to include a screenshot of what I see in my browser w/o having to have a reputation of over 10? I tried earlier but was denied access.

Comment: Do you have any syntax errors **after** the working style? (missing semicolon, quote, etc)

Comment: I don't think so. I've ran both the html and css through online validators and they both seem to be correct regarding syntax. Have you seen any errors when parsing through my code?

Comment: It's tough to tell since you've only got a snippet here. If one style is being applied, they all should be applied. Have you tried clearing your browser cache? (Sometimes this gets me, and I actually force my pages not to cache because it's such a headache)

Comment: I've cleared the cache and it's still not working properly. Is there another way to include a screenshot of my desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I assume that `text-decoration: underline` not work, try adding

```
.smedia-icons li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```